# Realm JS Try...Catch block returns both error and success promises

Tags: javascript, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When the code below is executed with the correct values, the object is deleted and the function returns both "Success" and "Error: object must be of type 'object', got (undefined)". So, the function is working because it deletes the object, but I shouldn't be getting any error message.

```
this.del = async function (arg1, arg2) {
    openR = openRealm(arg1);
    const realm = await Realm.open(openR);
    try {
    realm.write(() => {
    const del = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(openR.schema[0].name, arg2);
    realm.delete(del);
    });
    } catch(e) {
    return Promise.resolve(e);
}   
    return Promise.resolve("Success");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the code. It's just React Native reloading the component after the promise is resolved, and so calling the function again.

Comment: I would say the function should not be called twice, so this isn't really an 'answer' per se.

Comment: @Jay I answered my own question after I tested it with an alert() and a counter, and confirmed all functions inside the component are called twice. I'm building a plugin, so I'm sure the problem wasn't with the plugin code, but with my test environment. I'm using the React demo app to test it, so there isn't much to look into.